# How to save an integer in two digits in Dart

Tags: dart

How can I save an integer in two digits in Dart?

```
int i = 3;
String s = i.toString();
print(s);
```

The result should be **03** and  not **3**

Answer (score 65, accepted):

```
String s = i.toString().padLeft(2, '0');
```

Answer (score 0):

To save the first two digits of an integer.

```
 int val = 1546090;
 print(val);
 print(val.toString().substring(0,2));
```